# Another way to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?

Tags: lightdm, unity-greeter

I began having the infamous "system running in low graphics mode" error after my daughter turned off the power so she could boot into Windows.

Looking at the lightdm log in in `/var/log/lightdm/` showed that the greeter was failing to be created.

The greeter log showed that the greeter could not create its `.Xauthority` file.

Comment: It's protected, and my association bonus doesn't count toward the 10 reputation I need to add my answer to a protected question.  Yes, it is definitely a duplicate of the master question.